# Dual booting Ubuntu with Windows 10 - UEFI USB not booting

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, multi-boot, uefi

I have never had issues dual booting my Windows machines with Ubuntu (pre Windows 10). I made my bootable USB, started working through the Ubuntu live installer but when it came time to allocate disk-space, Windows wasn't showing up and I received the message "*This computer currently has no detected operating systems*".

I dove back in to my BIOS to double check both **secure boot** and **fast boot** were disabled - they were.

I then went back in to my *Boot Options* and saw that there were in fact 2 lables for my bootable USB, one for UEFI and another for Legacy.

When I attempted to select the UEFI *version* of the USB, the screen would go black for a second, then return back to the same *Boot Options* page. Clicking the "KingstoDataTraveler G3", my USB would fire up as described above (claiming no other operating systems were on the HD).

From what I gather, installing from UEFI is mandatory for W8/W10 machines for dual booting as described on the [Ubuntu Doc site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).

Any idea how I can get things up and running?

PC Specs: Asus MOBO x97, Current OS: W10, Desired dual-boot OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ubuntu is 100% compatible with secure boot.  If you your storage device is using a GPT partition schema, then you can't use legacy mode, furthermore UEFI IS NOT mandatory for Windows 8 and Windows 10 installations.  Any documentation that says otherwise is 100% incorrect.  The answer to [this](http://superuser.com/questions/315212/windows-7-ubuntu-dual-boot-uefi-bios?rq=1) question still applies to Windows 8 and Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked my disk properties in *Disk Management* and confirmed the partition schema is GPT. As per your reply, this suggest I cannot use legacy (and as explained in my question, UEFI is not launching). Would my best course of action be to shrink my disk volume in Windows in hopes that the Ubuntu installer will at least locate the *unallocated space*?

Answer (score 1):

If the Ubuntu "Something Else" path shows no partitions but you're 100% sure that the disk is partitioned, chances are either your partition table is damaged or you've got some RAID weirdness going on (like leftover RAID data on the disk or inconsistent RAID settings). I recommend:

1. Boot the Ubuntu installer into its "try before installing" mode.
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Launch `gdisk` on the disk (as in `sudo gdisk /dev/sda`, assuming the disk is `/dev/sda`).
4. In `gdisk`, type `p` to view the partition table followed by `v` to verify the disk. This may provide clues about what's going on. At this point, what to do depends very much on what `gdisk` says at this point.

You may want to read the [`gdisk` documentation on repairing GPT disks.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) If you need help, post back with more details, like the output of `gdisk` from step #3 and #4, above. Note that I'm the author of `gdisk`.